how to invoke sse from other files
I'm using nextjs with App Router + Page Router mixed.
The reason I mixed up two routers is because I could only figure out how to implement SSE using pages router. App Router uses Response interface which is defined in fetch context, while Page Router uses http.ServerResponse which is same as express.
So, I have a route handler in one file:
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-transform');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  res.flushHeaders();

  res.write(`data: 0\n\n`);

  res.on('close', () => {
    res.end();
  })
}

But then as you can see res is only available in this handler function. I want to send data when other api happens. Since I cannot export this res object, instead I created a EventEmitter that receives an event when its property changes.
class Counter extends EventEmitter {
  count: number;

  constructor(count = 0) {
    super();
    this.count = count;
    return;
  }

  setCount(count: number) {
    this.count = count;
    this.emit("change", this.count);
  }
}

export const counter = new Counter(0);

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-transform');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
  res.flushHeaders();

  counter.addListener("change", (count) => {
    console.log("change!", count);
    res.write(`data: ${count}\n\n`);
  })

  res.on('close', () => {
    res.end();
  })
}

And now I import this counter then call .setCount method which then triggers change event so that it sends Client the data through SSE.
"use server"

import { getSession } from "@/app/lib/auth"
import prisma from "@/app/lib/prisma";
import { counter } from "@/pages/api/sse";
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";


export async function assignTo(issueId: number, accountId: number) {
  await prisma.issue.update({
    where: { id: issueId },
    data: {
      assignee: { connect: { id: accountId } },
      status: { connect: { value: "pending" } }
    }
  });
  counter.setCount(10);  // <--- this doesn't trigger SSE!
  revalidatePath("/issues");
  revalidatePath(`/issues/${issueId}`);
}

But this doesn't work. Even thought I call .setcount method in other files (exactly speaking, server actions) change event doesn't seem to get triggered. Why not? Or is there any other way that I could trigger SSE?
